# A Thousand-Year War

Tags: internal-consistency, warfare, space-colonization

Okay, what conditions would allow a war fought exclusively on a single, Earthlike, planet last a thousand years? There are two sides: The native species, which has the support of an massive empire, and an species that wants to colonize the planet. The war is a hot war fought with infantry and vehicles.

Comment: Can you define what you mean with war within the scope of this question?

Comment: when you say massive empire do you mean that another empire is supporting the native cause?

Comment: This is a tough one as it gives few details and asks us to create the world around it for you - this requires solving about a million divergent issues and could lead to many, many different (and equally valid) answers. How can we tell what the best answer would be?

Comment: Why does the war need to last a thousand years? That's long enough to go from fireworks to nuclear robots on another planet, after all. War is often associated with rapid technological improvements, too. A thousand years of war between starfaring states which are also locked in technological stasis? Sounds pretty dubious. Seems like someone would have invented a postsophont AI, or general purposes nanotech, or mind uploading or _something_ to either break the stalemate or render the underlying cause pointless.

Comment: There's a real world analogous to this scenario. The arabes and berbers invaded Iberia and e took the christian 7 centuries to get rid of them. The natives had support of a powerful empire in the form of french interventions, and the colonists had access to a distant homeland where man and resources were pulled from in the form of the islamic world.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a war like this to last 1000 years, you'd need a few main conditions.

### Both sides must be equal

The first is that both sides are very similar in terms of their 'strength'. There's a lot of ways to define how strong a side is (numbers, technology, resources, etc.). But essentially you would have to assume that neither side had an edge that would let them surpass the other.

### Both sides must progress at the exact same rate

Related to the first point, both sides would need to be able to advance in science, technology, and warfare at an equal rate. This means that both sides would either be in an ideal situation where people not fighting on the front lines can develop and research technology and strategies, or in a terrible situation where society cannot progress, or somewhere in between. I think it would be more likely that both sides would maintain an equal level with each other if it was difficult for either side to develop new strategies or technologies as there's less chance of one side stumbling on a war-ending solution, but you could make it work either way.

### There must be a very strong reason for the war to not end

Finally, the war would have to be worth dragging out for 1000 years for both sides (especially a hot war with continuous battles and loss of life), and also justifiable to the rest of their respective societies. In this case, if the non-native species will go extinct without the native's planet, you could probably have a rationale for this war. However, you'd also need a reason for why there could never been a compromise (the natives give some land to the invaders). This would have to be something more than 'we don't compromise with invaders' because 1000 years is a very long time. After a couple of generations, there would be more pressure to simply end the war in any way possible. So you'd need a physical reason why a compromise could never happen (maybe the invaders need to terraform the native's planet in a way which would make it un-inhabitable for the natives?).

Answer (score 4):

What makes this planet special? I can't imagine a thousand year war would be worth any colonization effort by the invaders. By this time the logical choice would be to pack up and move on to a planet without a powerful global empire.

However, there is a couple ways I can see this working.

1. The invading force is biologically hardwired for war. They have a massive expendable population that they don't mind pruning the weak out of. They are also imperialists who have probably subjugated neighboring planets rather than a species running from a dying homeworld. It would explain the insane amount of resources they have at their disposal to fight this war.
2. The natives are a species that the invaders fear will cause great destruction to them or other galactic civilizations if they become spacefaring. The purpose of the war is not necessarily colonization, but containment.